# C# yield Follow-up to the end. In my class

Tags: c#, yield, yield-keyword

I have class PlayList like below. I have Playlist instance favorite with song ID {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} I need execute this.

```
foreach(Song song in favorite.GetSong(4))
{
    //Somthing
}
```

this return me songs with id 1, 2, 3, 4. Next I execute this code.

```
foreach(Song song in favorite.GetSong(3))
{
    //Somthing
}
```

And I need return song with id 5, 6, 7. But I do not know how to do that. I need remember last returned item and next time start with next item. And if I execute this

```
foreach(Song song in favorite)
{
    //Somthing
}
```

I want return all song in playlist from last returned item (in this case 7) to end (8, 9 , 10). But this is not necessary.

```
internal class PlayList : IEnumerable<SongID>
{
    private List<SongID> songsInAlbum = new List<SongID>();

    public Song this[SongID id]
    {
        get
        {
            if (songsInAlbum.Contains(id))
            {
                return AllSongs[id];
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Song> GetSong(int maxReturn = Int32.MaxValue)
    {
        int wasReturned = 0;
        foreach (SongID id in songsInAlbum)
        {
            if (wasReturned < maxReturn)
            {
                yield return AllSong[id];
                wasReturned++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddSong(SongID id)
    {
        songsInAlbum.Add(id);
    }

    public IEnumerator<SongID> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return songsInAlbum.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: Your requirements go against the general behaviour of `foreach`, where iterating over something doesn't change its state. While it would be possible to implement this, it would be better to modify your design to be more idiomatic.

Comment: @JonSkeet Would it still be wrong if GetSong returned a new IEnumerable and he didn't yield in the accessor?

Comment: @Dan: It's odd for the method returning a set to modify the state of the object, IMO. I realize that's not quite the same as my previous comment, mind you... It still just feels a bit strange to me.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, completely agree. As I said (before edit, sorry), I was ignoring his internal implementation and judging the proposed interface.

Comment: It sounds like you're after a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's better not to go against convention here, that will be maintenance nightmare. I'll keep the expected behaviour **of `foreach`**. Instead you can have another overload to enumerate the *rest of the songs*.
2. I would use `Skip` and `Take` for this purpose, ie in `GetSong` method, much simpler that way.
3. `GetSong` is a poor name for a method that returns a sequence. I would rename it to `GetSongs`, but I prefer a more descriptive name like `GetNext` or just `Next`.
4. To get the remaining songs, another overload makes more sense here. I'm a fan of optional arguments, but in this case I wouldn't want it.

So here we go

```
internal class PlayList : IEnumerable<SongID>
{
    private List<SongID> songsInAlbum = new List<SongID>();
    int currentIndex = 0; //maintain an index per instance; 1-based

    int Count //make it public if it makes sense
    {
        get { return songsInAlbum.Count; }
    }

    public Song this[SongID id]
    {
        get
        {
            if (songsInAlbum.Contains(id))
            {
                return AllSongs[id];
            }
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Song> Next(int noOfSongs)
    {
        try 
        {
            return this.Skip(currentIndex).Take(noOfSongs).Select(x => AllSong[x]);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (currentIndex < Count)
                currentIndex += Math.Min(Count - currentIndex, noOfSongs);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Song> Next() //or 'Rest', sounds good.
    {
        return Next(int.MaxValue); //less readable
        //or
        return Next(Count); //a more meaningful number
        //or
        return Next(Count - currentIndex); //for correctness
    }

    public void AddSong(SongID id)
    {
        songsInAlbum.Add(id);
    }

    public IEnumerator<SongID> GetEnumerator() //general enumerator, enumerates them all
    {
        return songsInAlbum.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
foreach(Song song in favorite.Next(4))
{
    //1, 2, 3, 4
}

foreach(Song song in favorite.Next(3))
{
    //5, 6, 7
}

foreach(Song song in favourite.Next())
{
    //8, 9, 10
}

foreach(Song song in favourite)
{
    //1, 2, ... 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain old enumerator: call GetEnumerator of your list and then iterate with that. This is what foreach calls beneath the curtains. This is the construct which does exactly what you want: it lets you iterate one by one and remembers where you are in the iteration.